# Scroll With Down Arrow in Puppeteer

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

So I am working on a feature in my app that disables scroll by arrow key on the body when a menu is open, and leaves the behavior alone otherwise.

I am attempting to test that behavior in Puppeteer, but I can not seem to get the window to scroll when I press arrow down. Here's some examples of what I am doing both in implementation and in my tests:

```
        const disableArrowScroll = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            if (
                isOpen &&
                (event.key === 'ArrowDown' ||
                    event.key === 'ArrowUp' ||
                    event.key === 'ArrowLeft' ||
                    event.key === 'ArrowRight')
            ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        };
```

```
it('does not effect scroll when menu is closed', async () => {
    await menuClosed(); // Times out if menu is not closed
    await page.focus('body');

    await keyboard.press('ArrowDown');

    expect(await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollY > 0)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I've ensured that the page should be scrollable by limiting the viewport, and am really at a loss as to why `window.scrollY` remains 0. Am I missing something? In an actual running demo, the code seems to run as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, after initiating the arrow down keypress, you need to give the page time to scroll down. You can do that by changing...

```
await keyboard.press('ArrowDown');
```

...to...

```
await keyboard.press('ArrowDown');
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Wait 1s
```

Comment: you can use puppeteer's "waitForTimeout" as well eg: await waitForTimeout(1000)